# How to use multiple condition in mongoDb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, conditional-statements, nosql-aggregation

**Write  query to find the restaurant Id, name, and grades for those restaurants which achieved a grade of "A" and scored 11 on an ISODate "2014-08-11T00:00:00Z" among many of survey dates..**

*My answer is as :

```
db.resCollec.find( { "grades.date": ISODate("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z"), 
"grades.grade":"A" , 
"grades.score" : 11 },
 {"restaurant_id" : 1,"name":1,"grades":1} );
```

- 

> This solution is not correct.What should i change in it

[The solution is not correct though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjU0Q.png)

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare "grades.date" to an exact date and time? If it could be anytime on 11/08/2014, then you could use "$gte" and "$lt" to check an interval instead: `"grades.date": {$gte: ISODate("2014-08-11T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2014-08-12T00:00:00Z")}`

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares ....but still the solutions from other dates are displayed along with grades and scores out of the one specified too.